# How do I perform cross validation before finding optimal parameters for my keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I want to perform cross-validation before picking my sequential model's optimal set of hyperparameters.

I understand that the key-error arises from the difference in columns between `x_train_scaled` column names and `cv_train` values. But how do I rectify it?

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential, layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold
```

Train-test split

```
# split the data into features and target
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

Standard scaling:

```
 def scale_datasets(x_train, x_test):
  """
  Standard Scale test and train data
  Z - Score normalization
  """
  standard_scaler = StandardScaler()
  x_train_scaled = pd.DataFrame(
      standard_scaler.fit_transform(x_train),
      columns=x_train.columns
  )
  x_test_scaled = pd.DataFrame(
      standard_scaler.transform(x_test),
      columns = x_test.columns
  )
  return x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled

# scale the dataset
x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled = scale_datasets(x_train, x_test)

for cv_train, cv_test in kfold.split(x_train_scaled, y_train):
```

Find optimal hyperparameter using keras tuner.

```
# Build the model with the optimal hyperparameters and train it on the data for 50 epochs
model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
history = model.fit(x_train_scaled.iloc[cv_train], y_train.iloc[cv_train], epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/4191267479.py in <module>
      4     # Build the model with the optimal hyperparameters and train it on the data for 50 epochs
      5     model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)
----> 6     history = model.fit(x_train_scaled.iloc[cv_train], y_train.iloc[cv_train], epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
      7 
      8     val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['val_accuracy']

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3462             if is_iterator(key):
   3463                 key = list(key)
-> 3464             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
   3465 
   3466         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
   1315 
   1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,  10,\n            ...\n            682, 683, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692],\n           dtype='int64', length=623)] are in the [columns]"
```

References:

- https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/
- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner

Comment: This is a pandas problem with a wrong column names in your `x_train_scaled[cv_train], y_train[cv_train]` these are wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your scale_datasets function gives you data frame objects back.
It is not needed.
That is also the reason why you get errors.

For numpy arrays you can retrieve **rows by index** by `ndarray[[0,1,2]]`
pandas dataframes will **look up a column** name `df[column]`.
`df.iloc[cv_train]` might work this normally looks up **rows by index** if it can handle this special data type.

---

There is no benefit or possible a negative impact on performance if you use a dataframe instead of the raw arrays.

Just go with

```
x_train_scaled = standard_scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
```

and keep them as arrays.
If they are a dataframe cast it to a numpy array `df.to_numpy()`

Comment: When I use `x_train_scaled = standard_scaler.fit_transform(x_train)`, I still get the same error. The `x_train_scaled` is now an array and I cannot use .iloc

Comment: when it's an array you dont need to use iloc anymore. That was the workaround if you use a datframe.